# How to force htaccess to remove last dash (-}

Tags: .htaccess, url

What I need:

force to HTTPS, remove WWW and remove last dash (`-`)

https://example.net/post/post-name-

I need it go to

https://example.net/post/post-name

I already have a Rewrite Rule that removes WWW and forces redirect to HTTPS. But if I do

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-$ https://example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

the rule to remove WWW don't work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

#force ssl and non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
#remove trailing hyphen "-" from uris
RewriteRule ^(.*)-$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```